Expectation value given a convex order
I want to know if the following proof is correct. Let $M,N$ and $X$ be random variables. If the following inequality holds for any concave non-decreasing function $u$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(N)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M)]
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(N+X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M+X)]
\end{equation}
My attempt: Suppose that $u´\leq C$ for some constant $C$. Given that $u$ is non-decreasing $u'\geq0$ and $u$ is concave, then
\begin{align*} 
   \mathbb{E}[u(N+X)-u(M+X)]&\leq \mathbb{E}[u'(M+X)(N-M)]\\
   &\leq C\mathbb{E}[N-M]\\
   &= C(\mathbb{E}[N]-\mathbb{E}[M])\\
   &\leq 0 
  \end{align*}
where the last inequality holds by the hypothesis using $u(x)=x$. Given that $C$ is arbitrary then is possible to conclude that for any $u$ (not necessary bounded) $\mathbb{E}[u(N+X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M+X)]$.
